# Insert an item to array object using underscorejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I want to insert an id in to an existing array of objects using underscorejs.

**input array**

```
var arr = [{name:"iPhone"}, {name:"Samsung"}];
```

**expected output array**

```
var arr = [{name:"iPhone", owner_id: "555"}, {name:"Samsung", owner_id: "555"}];
```

Tried following, its working but looking for a better way

```
devices = []
arr.forEach(function(data) {
    var device = {};
    device.owner_id = "555";
    device.name= data.name;
    devices.push(device )
})
```

Comment: are the `owner_id`s same for all objects in `arr`?

Comment: Loop over the array, adding the new property to each element.

Comment: Unless you tell us the problem you have with current method, we  cannot suggest anything "better".

Comment: Your problem would be better expressed as "I want to create a new array containing objects from an input array, with each object having a new `owner_id` property". In other words, you are not "inserting an item to array"; you are "inserting a property into each element in an array".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use underscore. Here is an easy way using the **.map** method. Each object returned inside the callback will be inserted into the devices array.

```
var devices = arr.map(function(data) {
    var device = {};
    device.owner_id = "555";
    device.name= data.name;

    return device;
})
```

If you console.log **devices** it will print (depending on data of course):

```
[{name:"iPhone", owner_id: "555"}, {name:"Samsung", owner_id: "555"}];
```

Comment: `return Object.assign({}, data, {owner_id: "555"})` would be easier. Or just `return {name: data.name, owner_id: "555"};`.

Comment: Yeah it would be. But you can easily implement logic into the .map callback! I'm sure the OP is just looking for a guide to get started on something more complex :D @torazaburo

Answer (score 2):

zip them first and then using  map

```js
var arr = [{name:"iPhone"}, {name:"Samsung"}];;
var ageArr = [{owner_id: "555"},{owner_id: "555"}];

var newArr = _.zip(arr, ageArr).map(function(v) {
    return _.extend(v[0], v[1]);
});

console.log(newArr);
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
```